# DataStax OpsCenter in ubuntu 12.04 not working

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm new to DataStax OpsCenter and cassandra and i wish to try it out. I followed the steps in the site ( http://www.datastax.com/docs/opscenter/install/install_deb ) and did it without getting any error. i'm using ubuntu 12.04 .

```
sudo service opscenterd start
```

This dosen't show any error or any other message.And when  i try to run it from browser i get unable to connect error. Please do help me to solve it. the opscenter is free edition.

Comment: you should check the opscenter log for errors. It is located at /var/log/opscenter/opscenterd.log. Also you will need root privileges to open it.

Comment: @hablema ,just check that interface and post written in /etc/opscenter/opscenterd.conf is same as what you had written in URL

Answer (score 1):

After you started it, you could check to ensure it's running

```
ps aux|grep opscenterd
```

If it is, then you may not have set the right IP in the opscenterd.conf log.  Step 6 at the installation docs (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/3.2/webhelp/index.html?pagename=docs&version=opscenter&file=install/install_deb#opsc/install/opscInstallDeb_t.html) says:

> Set the [webserver] interface to the hostname or IP address of the
>   OpsCenter machine in the /etc/opscenter/opscenterd.conf file. For
>   example:
>
> [webserver ] port = 8888
>   interface = 10.183.170.161

Obviously, instead of 10.183.170.161, you'll want to use a publicly accessible IP for this machine.

Answer (score 0):

if you're still having issues you should bind the opscenterd to 0.0.0.0 to ensure it's running ok and would be accesible.

also if your running it on AWS be sure to check that the security group has the port 8888 opened.